# PHP if status with OR not behaving as expecting

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to use an if statement in a foreach loop to check if a value of an array is not "finished" OR "executing"

```
$array = [
            $request1 = [
                            'title' => "foo",
                            'status' => 'finished'
                        ],
            $request2 = [
                            'title' => "bar",
                            'status' => 'executing'
                        ],  
            $request2 = [
                            'title' => "foo bar",
                            'status' => 'foo'
                        ]
        ];


foreach ($array as $request) {
    if ($request['status'] != 'finished' || $request['status'] != 'executing') {
        echo $request['title'];
    } 
}
```

I'd expect this to only return "foo bar", but it returns "foobarfoo bar"
What am I doing wrong here?

https://3v4l.org/VTVO5

Comment: `$request['status']` cannot be both `finished` *and* `executing` at the same time, so it *not being equal* to one or the other will always be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should use an AND operator, otherwise the condition is always true.

```
if ($request['status'] != 'finished' && $request['status'] != 'executing')
```

a variable will always differ from at least one of two values.

Comment: But it's either finished or executing not both

Comment: "is not equal to finished OR not equal to executing", think about it @Michael

Comment: You are not checking if the value equals, you are checking if it does not equal the value.

Comment: oh I see if I would be checking another variable for example 'status' and 'title' it should be ||/or